How to fix Base template shown as string?
In my dev environment, the base template under Data becomes a pipe separated string instead of a Listview. How do I fix that?


You are looking at raw values of fields. Just uncheck below checkbox to display multi selection list -

Hope this helps !

Sitecore consistently stores field values as plain text within the relevant Sitecore database. For basic fields like Single Line Text, there's no distinction between the displayed and original values; they're simply plain text. This differs for more complex field types like General Link, Image, or Rich Text.
Consider the raw value of a General Link field, for example. If you enable raw values in the Content Editor (by navigating to the View tab and selecting Raw values), and inspect an item with a General Link field, you'll observe that the value stored in the database is custom XML:
It is the same for List type and multi-list fields enabling users to make multiple selections through two multi-line select lists. The formatted, structured interface offers convenience for content authors. The chosen items are stored as a pipe-delimited list of item IDs.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
So if you do not want to see raw values then uncheck Raw values checkbox, inside `View' in the ribbon bar.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/XB7gb.png

Sitecore uses SQL Server to store most of its content. While content authors will see formatted text and structured content in the Content Editor and Experience Editor, Sitecore stores all data in a raw form in its database tables.
The best way to understand how Sitecore stores various data types is to enable "Raw Values" in the Content Editor. To do this, click on the View tab on the Content Editor ribbon. Enable the Raw Values checkbox. A warning message should appear on all items to remind users that they are seeing raw values in item fields.

In your case, you need to uncheck the Raw Values checkbox under View menu tab and you will be able to see what you want.
Hope this helps.

Navigate to the "View" option in the ribbon and deselect "Raw values" to switch the template to ListView format instead of displaying reference IDs.


Can you check if the raw values are enabled. You can navigate to View tab to check the same.

You can uncheck raw values button in order to get back the list view.
Hope this helps!!!
